# TypeScript .d.ts declarations not detected when using checkJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'd like to add Type definitions to an existing JavaScript codebase

I'm trying to define a function in my `index.d.ts`:

```
declare function func(): () => 42;
```

In `index.js`:

```js
// NOT type-checked
const func = () => {};
```

The `jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ES6",
    "noEmit": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "strict": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

While imports and explicit JSDoc comments related to the `.d.ts` are typechecked correctly, the `func` type declared in the `.d.ts` file looks not detected

[image]

Not sure if it is intented behaviour, bug or misconfiguration

The full repro is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/revolunet/test-jsconfig)

Comment: I would be very surprised if it worked. After all, declaration files are the output of `tsc`, why would they be used to recursively check the source? I imagine there are two ways to go about it: write declaration files and test them, as if you were contributing to DefinitelyTyped, or turn the project to a TS project incrementally.

Comment: What surprise me is that it works when importing the file in another one, but not in the file directly.
what do you mean by "write declaration files and test them, as if you were contributing to DefinitelyTyped" ?
PS: i authored the .d.ts manually

Comment: When you import, TS always looks for declaration files, so I am not surprised that this bit works. — Concerning testing, I mean having a separate file where you import your functions and expect errors or types instead of runtime values: so it's not the language server that automatically checks your types, you do it explicitly. You can look up `tsd`, which is a separate tool, or you can use a type-level assertion library and let the language server or `tsc` run your tests. I wrote `ts-spec` which mimics the API of a test runner but there are probably myriads of them

Comment: Got it for testing part, thanks. Still dont get why VSCode isnt able to auto-detect types for current file, but only for imports or explicit JSDoc types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the type explicitly, like so:

```
// index.d.ts
declare namespace MyNamespace {
  type MyFunc = () => 42;
}
```

```js
/** @type {MyNamespace.MyFunc} */
const func = () => 42;
// const func = () => {}; // this will now yield an error
```

Comment: Yes, this works nicely thanks but i was looking for implicit typings from the .d.ts

Comment: Right. Unfortunately there's currently no way to do that. You'll need to explicitly set their types or just use JSDOC comments.